# Why do we consider positive values when taking root of $\cos^2 \theta$ (or any trigonometric function) has two values (i.e. positive or negative)?

Tags: trigonometry

Let's consider a question for example,

\begin{align}
      \sin \alpha &= \frac{5}{13}\\\\ 
       \cos^2 \alpha &= 1 - \sin^2 \alpha \\\\
      \therefore \cos^2 \alpha &= \frac{144}{169} \\\\
     So,\ \cos \alpha &= \pm\frac{12}{13}\
     \end{align}
Still, the value we consider to find tan alpha (which is sin alpha/cos alpha) is the positive value of cos alpha.

Why is it so?

Comment: We do not always consider the positive value only; in fact, in most context I've seen an answer consisting of only the positive value would be incorrect, and one should provide both possibilities. If there are additional restrictions on $\alpha$ then we can potentially say more, but as is you should provide both possibilities.

Comment: You need information on $\alpha$ (for example $\alpha \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$) to know the sign of $\cos(\alpha)$, otherwise, you can not choose between the two possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no strict reason to only accept the positive answer; it all depends on what quadrant you expect $\alpha$ to fall into. However, sometimes it's beneficial to restrict the range to the first quadrant, $\alpha \in [0,\pi/2]$, where both $\sin \alpha$ and $\cos \alpha$ are positive (as in, nonnegative). This is especially the case early into trigonometry where you're only just considering the ratios of the sides of a triangle.

Generally, for any $x \in [-1, 1]$ such that $\cos^2 \alpha = x$, $\alpha$ is of the form $\alpha = k\pi \pm \beta$ for integers $k$ and real $\beta \in [0, \pi/2]$. (Exercise: find $\beta$.)